# Connect signal after hold mouse button for 10 secs PyQt Python

Tags: python, pyqt

I want to send "connect" signal after clicking and holding a button for certain time. After that time pass (f.e 10 seconds) the action or event will be triggerd even if button is not released. It could be  combinations of clicking or holdin for a while or anything different then just click and releasing the button.

Comment: I have a question, should the signal be emitted if the button is released before the threshold (10 sec)?

Comment: let say the treshold is 10 seconds. you should press the button for 10 seconds. after that an action should pop up like "you held it for 10 seconds". Shashank answer it down below. If I do
 `if self.held_time>10.0000:`
           `print('alo')`  in mouse_event_check() it will work like I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code I tested on PyQt4

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import * 

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        #Creation of a sample Window
        self.textLabel = QLabel()
        self.textLabel.setText('This is a Sample Window')
        box = QHBoxLayout(self)
        box.addWidget(self.textLabel)

        #Create a Timer
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(lambda: self.mouse_event_check())
        self.held_time = 0

        #Create Sample Button
        self.button = QPushButton('SAMPLE BUTTON')
        box.addWidget(self.button)

        #Connect Signals Pressed and Released
        self.button.pressed.connect(self.button_pressed)
        self.button.released.connect(self.button_released)

        self.timer_button = QTimer()
        self.timer_button.timeout.connect(lambda: self.button_event_check())
        self.button_held_time = 0

    # =========================================================================
    # Implementation for Buttons
    # =========================================================================
    def button_pressed(self):
        self.timer_button.start(50)

    def button_released(self):
        self.timer_button.stop()
        print('Button Held for {:.4f} seconds'.format(self.button_held_time))
        self.button.setText('{:.4f} seconds'.format(self.button_held_time))
        self.button_held_time = 0 

    def button_event_check(self):
        self.button_held_time += 0.05

    # =========================================================================
    # Implmentation for Mouse Held on Window
    # =========================================================================
    def mousePressEvent(self, mouse_event):
        self.timer.start(50)

    def mouse_event_check(self):
        self.held_time += 0.05

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, mouse_event):   
        self.timer.stop()
        print('Mouse Held for {:.4f} seconds'.format(self.held_time))
        self.textLabel.setText('Mouse Held for {:.4f} seconds'.format(self.held_time))

        self.held_time = 0


if __name__ == '__main__':  
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

#### Algorithm for Mouse Hold on Window

1. Create a `held_time` variable. Set it to 0
2. Create a Timer
3. Connect timeout() signal of timer to a function (`mouse_event_check`)
4. Reimplement `MousePressEvent()`

   - Start the Timer (50msec)
5. Reimplement `MouseReleaseEvent()`

   - Stop the Timer
   - Reset `held_time` to 0
6. Implement `mouse_event_check()`

   - Increase the held_time variable by 0.05

#### Algorithm for Mouse Hold on Button

1. Create a `button_held_time` variable. Set it to 0
2. Create a Timer
3. Connect timeout() signal of timer to a function (`button_event_check`)
4. Connect the button signals `pressed` and `released` to some callables
5. Implement `pressed` method

   - Start timer (50msec)
6. Implement `released` method

   - Stop Timer
   - Reset `button_held_time` to 0
7. Implement `button_event_check()`

   - Increase the held_time variable by 0.05

Comment: I have a problem about `mouse_event`. Is that work with a pushButton? or did buttons have something similar ? (like; button_event)

Comment: I have added implementation for  `QPushButton` using builtin signals `pressed` and `released`. I hope this helps.

Comment: The same one can be modified to test for 10 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import * 

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.textLabel = QLabel()
        button = QPushButton("Click me")
        button.clicked.connect(self.clickedButton)
        grid = QGridLayout(self)
        grid.addWidget(self.textLabel)
        grid.addWidget(button)

    def clickedButton(self):
        QTimer.singleShot(3000, self.passed3seconds)                # <---

    def passed3seconds(self):
        self.textLabel.setText("3 seconds passed \n do something")

if __name__ == '__main__':  
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: That work fine but it is not what I asked. You click the button and only after you release it action works. It did not start working until you release the button. What I asked is you need to click and hold clicked for 3 seconds. If you release before time finished, it  should abort the action.  

(I don't know maybe I'm asking something stupid. I'm new on this)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can rely on usage of [QTimer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html), i.e. when user clicks the button, you can start some QTimer instance with the specified interval, and when QTimer times out, then trigger a signal. In case user aborts the action, QTimer can be just reset, and then signal will not get triggered. The sample code can be seen below. However, it is in C++, but maybe it will not be a problem for you.

So, below is the definition of MainWindow:

```
#pragma once
#include <memory>

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui
{
    class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow
    : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    virtual ~MainWindow();

signals:
    void SomeTimerSignal(); // Signal we are eager to fire on the specific event.

public slots:
    void ButtonPressed(); // Button is clicked down.
    void ButtonReleased(); // Button is released.
    void OnTimeout(); // Timeout handling slot.

private:
    std::unique_ptr<Ui::MainWindow> m_ui; // UI mockup that is provided by Qt for us under the hood.
    QTimer* m_buttonTimer; // The timer we are going to control.
};
```

And now the code itself implementing this definition:

```
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QVBoxLayout>

#include "MainWindow.h"
#include "ui_MainWindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , m_ui(new Ui::MainWindow())
{
    m_ui->setupUi(this);

    // We could have chosen to instantiate timers on each signal, but it is much more efficient
    //   to create an instance of it once, and then use it appropriately.
    m_buttonTimer = new QTimer(this);

    // OnTimeout will get triggered after 10 seconds.
    m_buttonTimer->setInterval(10000);
    connect(m_buttonTimer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &MainWindow::OnTimeout);

    auto layout = new QVBoxLayout();
    auto button = new QPushButton();
    button->setText("Click and hold me!");
    button->setFixedSize(150, 50);
    layout->addWidget(button);

    m_ui->centralWidget->setLayout(layout);

    // Listen to button being pressed down: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#pressed
    connect(button, &QPushButton::pressed, this, &MainWindow::ButtonPressed);

    // Listen to button being released: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#released
    connect(button, &QPushButton::released, this, &MainWindow::ButtonReleased);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    // Button timer will be taken care by Qt through its' memory model.
}

void MainWindow::ButtonPressed()
{
    // Start the timer when button is pressed.
    m_buttonTimer->start();
}

void MainWindow::ButtonReleased()
{
    // Stop the timer, but don't delete it, since it can be reused.
    m_buttonTimer->stop();
}

void MainWindow::OnTimeout()
{
    // On timeout, we stop the timer, so it would not be triggered all over again when not needed.
    m_buttonTimer->stop();

    // And we fire some wanted signal.
    emit SomeTimerSignal();
}
```

In order to use this code, you would probably want to instantiate application in the following way:

```
#include "MainWindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

In other words, it is pretty basic Qt application in C++ that is filled in for you when creating your first Qt project if you are using Qt Creator. Hopefully, this code clarifies the idea how you could achieve what you want. In case you have any more questions, please ask it. Hopefully, I will be able to help you.